# mysql case statement not working properly

Tags: mysql

i know this is not a question that should asked in here. kindly help me to get a solution for this.

i am try to use case statement in the below query, bu i cant find the mistake that i have done in it. kindly help me..

```
SELECT
tsc_accessory_details_for_repaired_and_qc_pass_phone_list.Ccord
(CASE WHEN tsc_accessory_details_for_repaired_and_qc_pass_phone_list.Ccord == 'NVA' THEN 'NON_ValueAccessory'), 
COUNT(tsc_accessory_details_for_repaired_and_qc_pass_phone_list.Ccord) Ccord_count
FROM
tsc_accessory_details_for_repaired_and_qc_pass_phone_list
WHERE
tsc_accessory_details_for_repaired_and_qc_pass_phone_list.Ccord = 'NVA'
GROUP BY
tsc_accessory_details_for_repaired_and_qc_pass_phone_list.Ccord
```

am getting the error as follows

> SQL]SELECT
>       tsc_accessory_details_for_repaired_and_qc_pass_phone_list.Ccord
>       (CASE WHEN tsc_accessory_details_for_repaired_and_qc_pass_phone_list.Ccord == 'NVA' THEN 'ok'), 
>       COUNT(tsc_accessory_details_for_repaired_and_qc_pass_phone_list.Ccord) Ccord_count
>       FROM
>       tsc_accessory_details_for_repaired_and_qc_pass_phone_list
>       WHERE
>       tsc_accessory_details_for_repaired_and_qc_pass_phone_list.Ccord = 'NVA'
>       GROUP BY
>       tsc_accessory_details_for_repaired_and_qc_pass_phone_list.Ccord
>
> [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '== 'NVA' THEN 'ok'), 
>       COUNT(tsc_accessory_details_for_repaired_and_qc_pass_phon' at line 3

Comment: what is the error message that you are getting?

Comment: Jeez... are ALL your table names really that long and unwieldly?

Comment: Please tell us what it is doing that you dont want it to do. We are really bad guessers and it just wastes your and our time

Comment: You need to enter more context in your question. The Error you are getting and what output you are expecting?

Comment: [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '== 'NVA' THEN 'ok'), 
COUNT(tsc_accessory_details_for_repaired_and_qc_pass_phon' at line 3

Comment: Please feel free to use the `edit` link under the question to add more information.

Comment: Why you are using `==` rather a single `=`

Comment: Use = instead of == in following line CASE WHEN tsc_accessory_details_for_repaired_and_qc_pass_phone_list.Ccord == 'NVA'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table name is so long. You must use a shorter name or just use a synonym if this cant be shorten. Try this query -

```
SELECT ta.Ccord
      , (CASE WHEN ta.Ccord = 'NVA' THEN 'NON_ValueAccessory' END)
      , COUNT(ta.Ccord) Ccord_count
FROM tsc_accessory_details_for_repaired_and_qc_pass_phone_list ta
WHERE ta.Ccord = 'NVA'
GROUP BY ta.Ccord, ta.Ccord
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see some errors here.

- case when didn't terminated with `end case`
- select with group by can only take group by fields and aggregate results